# Replication Not Starting

Tags: couchdb, replication

`curl  http://usrname:password@192.168.1.10:5985/_active_tasks` shows the following.

In particular checkpointed_source_seq": 0. So my replication apparently isn't getting done. Is that due to a lack of response from the source server (iriscouch.org)?

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm also curious to know where the replication "logic" is happening, on the target or the source.

(I restarted my couchdb and the checkpointed_source_seq is still 0, but docs_read, docs_written, missing_revisions_found and revisions_checked all jumped to 5. And after sometime, everything is stuck at 5. The target is the old couchbase mobile running on Android, so maybe the problem is on the target and not a lack of response from the source.)

```
[
    {
        "pid": "<0.242.0>",
        "checkpointed_source_seq": 0,
        "continuous": false,
        "doc_write_failures": 0,
        "docs_read": 0,
        "docs_written": 0,
        "missing_revisions_found": 0,
        "progress": 0,
        "replication_id": "477dc6e34c791f161a2d47d742b349cd",
        "revisions_checked": 0,
        "source": "https://username:*****@myprj.iriscouch.com/myprj/",
        "source_seq": 342,
        "started_on": 1372285819,
        "target": "http://usrname:*****@0.0.0.0:5985/myprj/",
        "type": "replication",
        "updated_on": 1372287887
    }
]
```

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329935/couchdb-couchbase-replication-progress-monitoring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is using https vs http for replication, at least (and hopefully only) with iriscouch.com.

I came across [this post](https://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/how_to_replicate_to_local_couchdb_v_1_2_0_instance), switched to http and replication is now working OK. Except of course, my username and password are being sent in the clear.